# SSIS won't save DB password

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to test an SSIS package. I have a connection manager pointing to a SQL Server DB. I edit the Connection Manager, SQL Server Authentication is selected which is what I want. The user name field is filled out 'sqlServerUser', but the password field is blank. I fill out the password field, check "Save my password", test connection successfully and click OK.

But when I go to run the package it says login failed for user 'sqlServerUser'. I edit the connection manager again and the password field is blank again.

I can't test the package if it won't retain the credentials. How do I fix this?

Comment: That's the way it works. Otherwise your password is saved in clear text. In the first instance I recommend using windows authentication, not SQL authentication. If that doesn't work for you Look into "SSIS package protection levels".

Comment: Please check and post your package protection level. Try changing it to encrypt by user key for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way around this without changing the package protection level off of `DontSaveSensitive` is to use a configuration file with the connection string of the connection manager embedded. The password can be stored in the `dtsConfig` file.

Example:

```
  <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[DBConnection].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=192.168.45.21;User ID=sqlServerUser; password=myPassword; Initial Catalog=MyDB;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;</ConfiguredValue>
  </Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Authentication is by SQL Server Authentication, you can use the expressions for the Connection Manager and save the connection string on a project parameter.

[Connection string on project parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yf3x.png)

[Add expressions for the Connection Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvy3N.png)

As a result, the connection will always remain in the package\Solution.